# VB forms run time error, Adding columns to a Data Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, runtime-error

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim itemno As String
    Dim quantity, count As Integer
    count = count + 1

    itemno = TextBox5.Text
    Quantity = TextBox6.Text
    sql = ("SELECT ItemNo ,DishName, DishPrice FROM tblMenuInfo WHERE ItemNo = """ & itemno & """")
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    da.Fill(dsorder, "OrderInfo")
    If count = 1 Then
        dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Add("Quantity")
        dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Add("Sub total")

    End If
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo")

        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()


End Sub
```

Hi, I'm currently doing a ordering system project in school and am fairly new with VB forms

i have an access table called tblMenuInfo with the columns `ItemNo`, `DishName`, `DishPrice`.

I'm trying to add a column to my data table called Sub `Total` and `Quantity`. But I get the following error message

```
 {"A column named 'Quantity' already belongs to this DataTable."}
```

(Sorry I couldn't provide a print screen, I'm on a school computer)

My program only crashes on the second click.

Thanks In advance!

Comment: Where is dsorder defined?  When you click the button, it adds the column to the table.  When you click a second time, the column already exists from the first time you clicked.  You should probably define dsorder locally inside the button click.  Or at least, clear out the columns at the beginning of the button click.

Comment: dsorder was a public dataset, but I have now made it local. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first click the datatable contains following columns

```
ItemNo|Dishname|Dishprice|Total|Quantity
```

If you click the second time, your datatable still contains those columns.

```
ItemNo|Dishname|Dishprice|Total|Quantity
```

When the code reaches the following point:

```
    dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Add("Quantity")
```

The compiler says: "Hey i can't add that column! That column is already present in the datatable"

What you actually need to do: is check if the column is already present or clear the datatable of that dataset

**Solution 1:** Clear datatable after click

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

Dim itemno As String
Dim quantity, count As Integer
dsorder.Tables.Clear()
```

**Note on solution 1:** All data contained by the ds will be lost

**Solution 2:** Check if the column is present

```
'Check if datatable exists
If (dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo") IsNot Nothing) Then
     'Check if column exists
     If Not dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Contains("Quantity") Then
         dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Add("Quantity")
         dsorder.Tables("OrderInfo").Columns.Add("Sub total")

     End If
End If
```

Comment: Cheers mate! have fun!